# Create new `int` subtype mypy compatible with `int`

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I wanna extend the `int` type in a way `mypy` still recognizes it as int. Eg:

```
class u8(int):
    _size_bits = 8
    _struct_format: str = 'B'

    def validate(self):
        "Internal function. Mypy shouldn't care about it"
        return 0 <= int(self) <= 255
```

so I can use

```
i: u8 = 10
```

but `mypy` gives the error

```
Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "int", variable has type "u8")
```

*Assume it's using PEP 563, ie. `from __future__ import annotations`.*

Casting it like this would work, but it would pollute, create unnecessary overhead, and it's needed to work in existing code **only changing the type hint, not the code**:

```
i: u8 = u8(10)
```

So the only change needed would be adding the type hint, not changing the rest of the code. And it should work fine without typing too. if I remove the library (assuming PEP 563), the code should runs fine, even if in this case it would give a error on Mypy:

```
from __future__ import annotations

i: u8 = 10  # Works OK without the u8 definition

i: u8 = u8(10)  # ERROR: u8 is not defined here.
```

I also tried using `abc.ABC` with register but it [doesn't works](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/2922):

```
class u8(int, ABC):
    ...

u8.register(int)
```

This seems to be a simple task and I must be missing something pretty obvious here, but all googling til now didn't help.

Comment: It's not clear what behavior you're expecting. `10` isn't an object of type `u8`. It's not going to have that `validate` method, or behave like a `u8` object in any meaningful way.

Comment: Just get going with `myvar = u8(10)`

Comment: I add some clarifications why I can't go with `u8(10)`. Also, the type hint is to be used by the tool I'm building, so I need to explicitly type hint it.

Comment: What result do you expect for ˋi: u8 = 256ˋ or ˋi: u8 = -1ˋ?

Comment: In the runtime, if the tool is being used and the validation is on, to Throw an exception in some part of the code when the tool is required to act (in this case, to pack (serialize) the class). It's not clear yet because I'm creating it, but the intention is to do runtime checks when needed.

Comment: I mean, what result do you expect from MyPy?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi nothing much: just understand that this type is an integer without complaints. No additional validation. The validate would be used by the tool in runtime. Maybe in the future, I could write a mypy plugin that uses this stuff, but the gains would be really little or almost nothing for static analysis. Anything useful statically would be too complex to worth writing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to stuff non-type information into your annotations for the benefit of a tool you're building. You've tried to do this by creating a subtype, but that doesn't mean what you want it to mean, and mypy is correctly raising an error.

A feature for what you want is coming in Python 3.9, with a backport available for most previous versions (3.5.3+ and maybe 2.7) in [`typing_extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/). It's the `Annotated` annotation, proposed in [PEP 593](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0593/). With `Annotated`, you can define

```
u8 = Annotated[int, whatever_arbitrary_data]
```

and annotate things like

```
i: u8 = 10
```

and mypy will recognize that `int` is the type and `whatever_arbitrary_data` is someone else's problem.

Comment: Actually I using python 3.9, so I will try this. The `Annotated[type, extra]` is ugly, but I forgot I can use it this way and it will likely be the perfect solution.

Comment: Indeed, in the PEP 593 document, it cites a hypothetic library that is exactly what I'm doing as an example.

Answer (score -1):

A workaround I found so far is to define the class as `int` when `TYPE_CHECKING` is true. The example above seems to let mypy happy and gives what I need in the runtime:

```
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING

class _u8(int):
    _size_bits = 8
    _struct_format: str = 'B'

    def validate(self):
        return 0 <= int(self) <= 255

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    u8 = int
else:
    u8 = _u8

i: u8 = 10
```

Comment: But then whenever you try to *actually use* `u8` for anything, [mypy will complain](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.8&gist=20a5a62b372c28422ddefb2a90fe4786) that `int` doesn't have the methods and attributes you're trying to use.

Comment: And if you never try to actually use `u8` for anything, then there's no point in creating it in the first place.

Comment: The validate method will be used inside the tool that creates the u8 type, so I can disable type checking per line basis. But giving the type hint of the tool shouldn't create an mypy error to the user that is using the u8 type.

Comment: More simply:
**inside the tool**: I can use u8.validate, and can use `# typing: ignore` when needed.  

**in the code using the tool**: Just adds the type hinting and import the tool, but doesn't change the rest of the code, neither creates a mypy error.